# Jquery toggle to keep an image open until last drop down is closed?

Tags: jquery

So I am using the following JQuery to shrink and expand the images on this WordPress page:  it works well for 1 drop down menu but I need more.

```
jQuery(function($) 
 {
    $('#fl-accordion-5bd9e6909a616-tab-0').click(function ()
    {
        $('.wp-image-2004').toggleClass("grow");
    });

 });
```

I have 3 accordion drop down menus in this div. I want the targeted image to "grow" anytime "1" of the  3 menus is opened and I want the image to return to its regular size when all 3 of the accordion menus are closed.

My issue is with the current code is my image will grow and shrink every time any of the 3 menus is opened or closed if I target more then 1 accordion drop downs.

I was thinking something along the lines of an if or else statement that would fire the function based on this line: aria-selected="false" or "true"

Any help would be appreciated I'm still learning JQuery and this task was more then I could handle.

So here is what I have now but im still having issues:

```
  $('.fl-node-5bd9e6909a5dd h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('visible');
  $('img').toggleClass('grow', $('.fl-node-5bd9e6909a5dd 
div.visible').length != 0);
});

CSS


img[src='http://prontoprogress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Help-sm-1- 
 700x467.jpg'] {
 width: 70%;
 transition: width 1s;
}
img[src='http://prontoprogress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Help-sm-1- 
 700x467.jpg'].grow {
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: The site I'm working on is http://prontoprogress.com/epicor-support
scroll down to "NEEDING HELP"

Comment: Try setting a separate state value for each menu and then each time one is closed, check the state for the other two and act accordingly (or accordionly as the case may be).

Comment: Even more succinct, give the 3 menus a class and then loop through them to check the state each time one is opened or closed.

Comment: Similar to @Difster, you could toggle a class, let's say `visible`, on the accordion panel, then check how many accordion panels have the `visible` class - if none, then remove the `grow` class from the corresponding image, otherwise, add the class (if not present). Something like this might do the trick - obviously you'd have to change selectors and remove my one-liner accordion functionality, but it gets the point across: http://jsfiddle.net/0bdgszew/

Comment: You all are awesome I appreciate the help! Thank you mark.hch for the jsfiddle that helps me as i'm a visual learner.

Comment: so let me update on what I have

Comment: Please take a look and let me know if I'm headed in the correction direction. I already hacked away at this for several hours yesterday as I'm a new. The Jfiddle worked fine but when trying on the website it was a no go. I'm wondering if the issue is other divs in the way? like <div < div< div< <h3>

Comment: @Turtle You can tag someone in your comments (@ then the username - it should give autocomplete suggestions) so they are notified when you reply - I didn't notice your reply, but just happened to open the post again to see if your issue was fixed. That being said, it likely does have something to do with your HTML structure. It looks like you've gone to 1 paragraph per div now, if you want further help, just make a Fiddle or something with your structure (leaving out anything personal or confidential) and we can work with that to troubleshoot.